# Behaviour matching

Tags: scala, behavior, matching

A little time ago I found an interresting blog entry, where someone showed how to ensure an object has a specific behaviour. Now I want to do so, but I can't find the blog. Can anybody show me the syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean structural types? Here is an example:

```
class Duck {
  def quack = "quack"
}

class OtherDuck {
  def quack = "mooh"
}

object Test {
  def testQuack (d: {def quack: String}) = d.quack
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Test.testQuack(new Duck)
Test.testQuack(new OtherDuck)
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with the right answer based on the super-vague question.

Comment: The correct name is "structural type", not actually duck typing.